# How to clear cache for swift chat app which uses Firestore as its database?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In my chatviewcontroller,when a user send another user a message, it will reload asynchronous to get the sent message or receive message. I would like to clear cache, after the user sent the message and before it reloads to get the new message.The reason why i want clear cache is because the previous message will messed with my new message as shown in the picture.If i close my chat and reopen, everything is fine which means its the cache problem.
[Image to View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zUKt.png)

```
  @IBAction func sendTextMessage(_ sender: Any) {
    chats.removeAll()
    self.sendDataToDatabase(message: messageText.text!)
    messageText.text = nil
     //Clear Cache here     (How to clear cache of a viewcontroller?)
    loadPosts()
    loadPostsReceivedMessage()
    delayCompletionHandler {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `observeEventOfType` which will keep your data in sync and will execute again as soon as any data changes in the backend related to what you are observing.

Alternatively, you can still use `observeSingleEventOfType`, this won't listen for changes on the backend but you can call `ref.keepSynced(true)` every time you want to refresh the data.

Comment: Hi Niall,all those have been done previously alr.But the issue now is the cache is messing up my message and i want to know how to clear cache.U can take a look at the image in my question, thks alot bro (:

Comment: Ah I see, difficult to see the issue completely. Do you think you could create a new conversation and label each message 1,2,3,4,5 etc so I can tell the order.

Comment: The message on the left is the message sent from user A to user B, the message on the right is the message received by user A from user B.Basically i need to clear all the messages from the view, before i can reload the messages again.

Comment: Is it duplicating the messages or is it it not correctly placing them in order?

Comment: When i click send message,it is duplicating the messages.I think it is a cache issue.When i exit the chat,enter the chat again, the duplicated messages are gone.

Comment: You should make sure that you clear your array every time it downloads all the messages

Comment: I did so,but it doesn't work..U can see my above code i already did:  chats.removeAll()

Comment: You need to clear the posts in `loadPosts()` right before you fetch them